# Handling errors in libcrypto BIO base64 decoding

Tags: c, error-handling, openssl, base64, libcrypto

I've been playing around libcrypto's BIO, and I can't find a way to detect errors during base64 decoding.

Even if data is complete garbage, `BIO_read` just returns zero, and error queue - as examined with ERR_get_error - remains empty.

The same issue happens with `BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL` flag: in case of mismatch (that is, data contains newlines, but the flag is set; and vice versa), there's no indication of error, there's just no data.

So, is there a way to catch decoding errors?

```
static unsigned char *base64_decode(unsigned char *data, size_t len, size_t *out_len)
{
    // chain should look like this
    // b64 - mem
    // so when we read from b64, it gets data from mem and decodes it

    BIO *bio_b64;
    BIO *bio_mem;
    size_t res_capacity;
    size_t res_size;
    unsigned char *res; 
    size_t ret;

    bio_b64 = BIO_new(BIO_f_base64());
    bio_mem = BIO_new_mem_buf(data, len); 
    res_capacity = 1024;
    res_size = 0;
    res = malloc(res_capacity);

    // don't care about newlines
    BIO_set_flags(bio_b64, BIO_FLAGS_BASE64_NO_NL);

    BIO_push(bio_b64, bio_mem);

    // empty error queue, just in case
    while (ERR_get_error() != 0);

    while (1) {
        ret = BIO_read(bio_b64, &res[res_size], res_capacity - res_size);
        if (ret == (res_capacity - res_size)) {
            res_size += ret;
            res_capacity *= 2;
            res = realloc(res, res_capacity);
        } else if (ret == 0) {
            break; 
        } else {
            res_size += ret;
        }
    }

    if (ERR_get_error() != 0) {
        free(res);
        return NULL;
    }

    BIO_free_all(bio_b64);

    *out_len = res_size;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately `BIO_read` does't emit an error if malformed data. You can either check expected size (4/3) or reimplement without openssl.